# Display Toast Message & Perform an action When a certain period of time has passed

Tags: java, android

I have an app where it reads through a file of numbers. A threshold is predefined and every number in the file is compared with the threshold, one by one. When the number read is greater than the threshold, display an alert with a button. If the button is not pressed for 2 minutes, send an sms message. And if the button is **still not pressed for another two minutes**, then make a phone call.

The bit I am struggling with is calculating the time passed and trigger one of the two methods mentioned earlier, after a certain time have passed. How to define it and where. I have seen plenty of examples using Handlers, timers and Runnable method, tried them with no success. When I run the app, nothing happens.

Here is my code so far, would appreciate any suggestions or ideas.

**Using Handler**

```
private static final int MISS_LIMIT = 1000;
int misses = 0;

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable timer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            handler.postDelayed(timer, MISS_LIMIT);
            // user too late: increment miss counter
            if (++misses >= MISS_LIMIT)
            {
                //TODO miss limit reached
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time is passed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish(); // close this activity
            }
        }
    };
```

And the rest of the code:

```
 int Threshold = 40;

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


    File file = new File(dir, "/Numbers.txt");

    try
    {
       FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);

       if (fin != null)
       {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
        String line ="";

        while((line= bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {

          if (Integer.parseInt(line) > Threshold)
          {
             //store value in integer
             int number = Integer.parseInt(line);

             // create alert dialog
             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                    builder
           .setTitle("Alert !!")
           .setMessage("High Temperature !!" + "\t" + number)


           .setPositiveButton("Send SMS",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)
              {
                // if this button is clicked, close current activity
                MainActivity.this.finish();
              }
            });


    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                                          alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.holo_red_light);
        alertDialog.show();
         }

    }

    fin.close();
```

Comment: I'd take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: Take a boolean flag and make it `false` on `OK` button click. After displaying dialogue you can call two `Handler.postDelayed()` methods, one for sms and one for call with different delays. In both `Runnables` check if boolean flag is true or false, if TRUE then send SMS or make call else do nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can make the following changes for the same to work.

Suppose you are invoking the Dialog from initiateDialog method

```
    void initiateDialog(){
    //Show Alert
    //Your existing code for Dialog
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.holo_red_light);
    alertDialog.show();
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    buttonNotPressedFirst();
                }
            }, FIRST_DELAY);

    }
    void buttonNotPressedFirst(){
         //SEND SMS
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    buttonNotPressedSecond();
                }
            }, SECOND_DELAY);
    }
    }

    void buttonNotPressedSecond(){
      //Proceed with phone call
    }
```

Comment: Where should I put the handler? Is it between the DialogButton.OnClickListener? Because if the `Send Sms` Button in the dialog, not pressed, then send a text and then make a phone call. When I put the handler after the `Listener Event` it shows the `postDelayed` in red.

Comment: The process to show your alert should be fully moved to method initiateDialog().  After alertDialog.show(); ,  start first handler. So that by the time you started showing Dialog alert, your first counter started. If the handler completes then  call buttonNotPressedFirst().

Comment: So how can I avoid starting the `SECOND_DELAY` from beginning, after the `FIRST_DELAY` has ended. Assuming that the `FIRST_DELAY` is `10000`. After it finishes, start `SECOND_DELAY` from where `FIRST_DELAY` has ended, not from `0`. Can this be achieved in anyway?

Comment: SECOND_DELAY is just a number specifying milliseconds of delay same as FIRST_DELAY .  In the above logic, once the first handler is finished, then only second handler starts. Otherwise make some simple logic with variables and numbers. A_10=B_3+C_7.   A is sum of B and C. You can manipulate that way. And that is just logic.